# Is there a way to parse JSON strings separated by commas into an array of JSON objects

Tags: javascript

If I have one big string that consists of json strings, Ex:

'{'animal' : 'dog', 'color': 'blue'}, {'animal' : 'cat', 'color' : 'green'}'

Is there a way to parse this into an array containing the JSON objects? JSON.parse() does not work.

Comment: Stick square brackets `[]` before and after, then it's a valid JSON array.

Comment: @lonesomeday — No. There are other errors that prevent it being JSON in addition to that.

Comment: @Quentin Ah yes. No more Stack Overflowing on my phone.

Answer (score 1):

Not really. It isn't JSON.

- A JSON array has to be delimited with `[` and `]`, but this is delimited with `'` and `'` (badly since those characters appear inside the text too).
- A JSON string has to be delimited with `"` and `"`, but this uses `'` and `'`.

You could:

- Fix the data manually
- Try to write some code to fix it up
- Write a custom parser to use instead of a JSON parser

Comment: Maybe you include it in "fix the data manually", but if not - "Make sure the original data is actually emitted as a valid JSON object/array." Assuming the source is another service that just produces invalid JSON-like data string, and something you can fix.